# Add jaeger trace id and span id to log4j2 logs

Tags: log4j2, opentracing, jaeger

I want to inject x-b3-traceid and x-b3-spanid in logs  with pattern as shown-

```
property name="PATTERN" value="%h %l %u [%date{dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss.SSS}] &quot;%r&quot; %s %b &quot;%i{Referer}&quot; &quot;%i{User-Agent}&quot; [trace=%responseHeader{X-B3-TraceId},span=%i{X-B3-SpanId}] %D"
```

For zipkins, there are libraries available like

> brave-context-log4j2 –
>   (https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/tree/master/context/log4j2)

Spring cloud sleuth. (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/)
How can I add that while using jaeger?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to move forward in order to use Jaegar is NOT TO USE JAEGAR CLIENT! Jaegar has the ability to collect Zipkin spans.

https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.8/getting-started/#migrating-from-zipkin

You should take advantage of this and use the below Sleuth+Zipkin dependency and exclude Jaegar agent jars in your spring boot app.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The above will send Zipkin spans to http://localhost:9411 by default. You can override this in your Spring Boot app to point to your Jaegar server easily by overriding the zipkin base URL.

```
spring.zipkin.base-url=http://your-jaegar-server:9411
```

Sleuth will do all the heavy lifting and the default logging will log the span and traceIds.

In the `log4j2.xml` file, all you have to mention is

```
[%X]
```

I'll be uploading a working example of this approach into my GitHub and sharing the link.

**EDIT 1:**

You can find the sample code here:

https://github.com/anoophp777/spring-webflux-jaegar-log4j2